# JavaFX8 Convert String to date using DateTimeStringConverter

Tags: date, javafx-8

I would like convert string to date (dd/MM/YYYY) - this is useful for compare dates in TableColumns.

so i use DateTimeStringConverter (the string "01/11/2014" is a value of DatePicker)

```
DateTimeStringConverter format = new DateTimeStringConverter(Locale.FRANCE,
  "dd/MM/YYYY");

Date d1 = format.fromString("01/11/2014");

d1.toString()
```

I don't obtain the right date but this date = "Mon Dec 30 00:00:00 CET 2013" !!!

I don't understand what is the problem (which in fact should not be a problem) ?

Any ideas ?

Thank you in advance

Fabrice

Comment: try using java.Calendar

Comment: The problem is the format : "dd/MM/yyyy" and not "dd/MM/YYYY" !

Comment: Do you want to convert it to `LocalDate` (new in Java 8) or `java.util.Date` (old) ?

Comment: The problem came simply from an error in the format "dd/MM/YYYY" -> "dd/MM/yyyy" and now it's ok thanks you for your help.